# Get message delivery status EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I need to send messages using  Exchange Web Services API and then check if they are delivered or not. To do so I tried to use EWS tracing, but log file always gives *NoError* status even if email I'm sending to doesn't exist.
Now I'm trying to get last messages in *SentItems* folder and check their properties, but I can't find the property for delivery status. What can I do with it? 
My code now:

```
private void checkDeliveryStatuses(ExchangeService service)
    {
        ItemView itemview = new ItemView(10);
        itemview.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId, *some property for status*);
        FindItemsResults<Item> newMessages = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, itemview);
        foreach (Item item in newMessages)
        {
            EmailMessage msg = item as EmailMessage; 
            //Somehow get delivery status here
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

The Delivery status isn't stored on the copy of the Message stored in the SentItems folder so what your trying to do won't work the way you trying to use it. EWS has some Message Tracking operation that you could try to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb409286(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_message_tracking there is no support for using these operation in the EWS Managed API so if you want to use them you will need to either using RAW SOAP or proxy objects eg

```
ExchangeServiceBinding esb = new ExchangeServiceBinding();
esb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
esb.Url = "https://servername/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
esb.RequestServerVersionValue = new RequestServerVersion();
esb.RequestServerVersionValue.Version = ExchangeVersionType.Exchange2010_SP1;
ReplyToItemType riRepItem = new ReplyToItemType();
FindMessageTrackingReportRequestType fmtRequest = new FindMessageTrackingReportRequestType();
fmtRequest.Scope = "Organization";
fmtRequest.StartDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4);
fmtRequest.Sender = new EmailAddressType();
fmtRequest.Sender.EmailAddress = "administrator@msgdevelop.com";
fmtRequest.Domain = "msgdevelop.com";
fmtRequest.StartDateTimeSpecified = true;
FindMessageTrackingReportResponseMessageType fmtResponse = esb.FindMessageTrackingReport(fmtRequest);
foreach (FindMessageTrackingSearchResultType fmtSearchResult in fmtResponse.MessageTrackingSearchResults)
{
Console.WriteLine(fmtSearchResult.MessageTrackingReportId);
GetMessageTrackingReportRequestType gmt = new GetMessageTrackingReportRequestType();
gmt.MessageTrackingReportId = fmtSearchResult.MessageTrackingReportId;
gmt.Scope = "Organization";
gmt.ReportTemplate = MessageTrackingReportTemplateType.Summary;
GetMessageTrackingReportResponseMessageType gmtResponse = esb.GetMessageTrackingReport(gmt);
foreach (RecipientTrackingEventType rte in gmtResponse.MessageTrackingReport.RecipientTrackingEvents)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rte.EventDescription);
    Console.WriteLine(rte.DeliveryStatus);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how do I get the ExchangeServiceBinding object? Now I have namespace error. I've tried to google it, but didn't help.

Comment: You need to generate the Web Service Proxy objects eg in Visual studio https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb408520(v=exchg.140).aspx (works the same as 2008 on 2010, 2015 and 2017)

Comment: Hello again. I get "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again." in fmtResponse. The credentials are correct. What could be wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the rights to track the message in the context your trying to use. Eg a user can only get the delivery status of Messages that they have sent (not other peoples messages). There is also and administrative RBAC role https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876858(v=exchg.150).aspx that can affect this in some contexts